# How to fix the App name on the top of the Activity

Tags: android-activity, android-actionbar

In my design page of My Android Studio Project, the App Name is shown in the top of the activity(Action Bar). But, when I debug the App, the App name is not Shown on the top of the Activity. I want the App name should be shown. How to fix it.

My styles.xml is...

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Comment: paste your `style.xml`

Comment: I have Pasted my styles.xml

Answer (score 1):

Set your App theme to `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` in `style.xml`

For e.g.

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you was asking about [ActionBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html)

***from docs***

> A primary toolbar within the activity that may display the activity
>   title, application-level navigation affordances, and other interactive
>   items.
>
> Beginning with Android 3.0 (API level 11), the action bar appears at
>   the top of an activity's window when the activity uses the system's
>   Holo theme (or one of its descendant themes), which is the default.
>   You may otherwise add the action bar by calling
>   requestFeature(FEATURE_ACTION_BAR) or by declaring it in a custom
>   theme with the windowActionBar property.

If you want to change it from java code, write in

**Activity.java**

```
ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
ab.setTitle("My new title");
```

Or, in the **Androidmanifest.xml** file:

```
<activity 
       android:name=".MyActivity" 
       android:icon="@drawable/my_icon" 
       android:label="My new title" />
```

hope my answer help you..